# Get next item each item a function is called

Tags: python-3.x, list

```
app = Flask(__name__)

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/msdfs/Downloads/cd79/chromedriver.exe', options=options)

driver.implicitly_wait(10)
links = ['http://www.dia.net/hottest/AllTime',
'http://www.dia.net/subcategory/ua7oawncuaxoa',
'http://www.dia.net/subcategory/ua7oawncuaxoa/test',
'http://www.edia.net/subcategory/ua7oawncuafou',
'http://www.dia.net/subcategory/ua7oawncuatla',
'http://www.dia.net/subcategory/ua7oawncuatla/testr',
'http://www.dia.net/subcategory/ua7oawncua7oc']

global go
go = iter(links)

@app.route('/')
def get_jokes():
    driver.get(next(go))
    facts = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('p')
    mylist = []
    for fact in facts:
        mylist.append(fact.text)
    return render_template('facts.html', s=mylist)
```

How make the template pull the next URL in the list of URLs every time the function is called? This method of course doesn't work. It is one of the many I have tried. Just to clarify, the list index should increase by 1 every time the function is called.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do this is this.

```
app = Flask(__name__)

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/msdfs/Downloads/cd79/chromedriver.exe', options=options)

driver.implicitly_wait(10)
links = ['http://www.dia.net/hottest/AllTime',
'http://www.dia.net/subcategory/ua7oawncuaxoa',
'http://www.dia.net/subcategory/ua7oawncuaxoa/test',
'http://www.edia.net/subcategory/ua7oawncuafou',
'http://www.dia.net/subcategory/ua7oawncuatla',
'http://www.dia.net/subcategory/ua7oawncuatla/testr',
'http://www.dia.net/subcategory/ua7oawncua7oc']




curr_index = 0
@app.route('/')
def get_jokes():
    global curr_index
    driver.get(links[curr_index])
    facts = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('p')
    curr_index += 1
    mylist = []
    for fact in facts:
        mylist.append(fact.text)
    return render_template('facts.html', s=mylist)
```